# Unable to make a serializable XUnit test class with OutputTestHelper

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

Is it possible to make an Xunit class using `IOutputTesthelper` (or any mean to generate output) and inheriting from `IXunitSerializable` in order to have the test cases show up as individual tests?

One way to create an Xunit class that uses `IOutputTesthelper` to generate output and inherits from `IXunitSerializable` is to implement the `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods of the interface. This allows the test cases to be serialized and deserialized by the test runner, and to appear as individual tests in the test explorer.

For example:

```
public class MyTestClass : IXunitSerializable, IOutputTesthelper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    public MyTestClass() { }

    public MyTestClass(string name, ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Name = name;
        Output = output;
    }

    public void Serialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        info.AddValue(nameof(Name), Name);
    }

    public void Deserialize(IXunitSerializationInfo info)
    {
        Name = info.GetValue<string>(nameof(Name));
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Alice")]
    [InlineData("Bob")]
    public void TestName(string name)
    {
        Output.WriteLine($"Hello, {name}!");
        Assert.Equal(Name, name);
    }
}
```

But this won't work since a test class should only define a single public constructor.

Comment: https://xunit.net/xunit.analyzers/rules/xUnit3001 suggests a some mitigation

Comment: The extra public constructor is being called when the unit tests are run. If the unit tests use the ITestOutputhelper, I will have NullReferenceException every time the tests run.